# What are Alias registers?

Tags: architecture, embedded, hardware, microcontroller

In reference to the hardware domain say an IP( a module for ex: UART) has some registers as alias registers to a register. [ This is just an example ]

The alias registers have different addresses compared to the original register for which they are aliased.

Can you please explain me about:

```
What are Alias registers ?

What is the need to have them ?
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: usually that means that the address decoder for something has more than one address that works, like a wrap around address.  Say you have a system with 64Kbytes of memory and the address decoder ignores address bits above 15 that means 0x10000 and 0x0000 and 0x30000 will all address the same item in memory.  And that is called aliased or wrapped around.  You could very well be in that same situation, perhaps the upper address bits are checked and lower but some in the middle ignored such that more than one address pattern accesses the same registers

Comment: @dwelch : That looks like an answer not a comment.  You can't get the credit you deserve posting answers as comments.

Comment: Credits are not my primary interest...was trying to feel out what the poster was really asking.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question:

> The alias registers have different addresses compared to the original register for which they are aliased.

That is exactly what an alias is; literally a different name for the same thing.  Specifically in this case a different address to the same physical register.

It is usually an artefact of incomplete address decoding. If you have an I/O space of say 256 registers, you only need 8 address lines, but if your address bus is 16 bits for example, it is simpler to leave the higher address lines unconnected that to explicitly decode them, so the I/O space repeats every 256 bytes (in this example). Otherwise you would have to OR the high order address lines together with the /CS line to avoid the aliasing to no particular benefit.

Comment: True. But, they have there own space. And the value changes in one reflects in  others. What's the use of this?

Comment: @UchiaItachi - saves on silicon.  If the controller has a large I/O adress range and a small number of I/O registers, it is not necessary to decode the full address for the registers.  This has the aparrent effect of making the same registers appear at multiple addresses.  It is not useful to the user, nor it it harmful to the user. It is, however, useful to the chip designer:)

Comment: @UchiaItachi : I have added to the answer in light of Martin's response to the your comment.